# Do any motherboard NOT use NOR flash to boot or have two BIOSes?

Tags: motherboard

My Z97 motherboard recently died. I suspected that it was the BIOS chip because I have heard stories in the past about some UEFI bioses being bricked by some settings changed.

I reflashed the device and it happened again. It happened a third time, so I am waiting for some components (through hole devices) to be sent from China.

Do recent chipsets still read the BIOS from NOR flash? Why is the UEFI writing to NOR flash. Could the NOR flash be wearing out? If mobo manufacturers are copying Intel and AMD reference designs, why don't these include a simple BIOS 0/1 switch and solder two SMD devices with a physical switch on the /CS so that you can easily program and switch between the two BIOSEs, as has been done on video cards for many years. I believe more recent chipsets show the SPI interface to program these in the devicetree/ACPI

Does any motherboard out there come with two NOR chips that are selectable?

Comment: There are mainboards available where you can flash the UEFI BIOS even without a CPU installed (mostly for AMD CPUs that way you can upgrade the UEFI for supporting the latest CPU generation without the need of buying an older first). I would assume that those boards use a separate flash-system so they should also work if the UEFI BIOS is in a non-working state.